# Delete/update Configurable Product with SOAP Api v2 Magento

Tags: api, magento, soap

I am trying to delete a configurable product in my cart wiht shoppingCartProductRemove with Api SOAP v2, but the api return

> Please specify the product's option (s)

this is my Soap requets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <v:Header />
   <v:Body>
      <shoppingCartProductRemove xmlns="http://dev.WEBPAGE.mx/index.php/api/v2_soap" id="o0" c:root="1">
         <sessionId>e6ad1063fd8f8a5b1637ec7b2bedb0ed</sessionId>
         <quoteId>1016</quoteId>
         <products>
            <shoppingcartproductentity>
               <product_id>5730</product_id>
               <sku i:null="true" />
               <qty>0.0</qty>
               <qtySpecified>false</qtySpecified>
               <options i:type="d:anyType"> 
                  <associativeentity>
                     <key>92</key>
                     <value>410</value>
                  </associativeentity>
                  <associativeentity>
                     <key>138</key>
                     <value>406</value>
                  </associativeentity>
               </options>
               <bundle_option i:type="d:anyType">
                  <associativeentity>
                     <key>92</key>
                     <value>410</value>
                  </associativeentity>
                  <associativeentity>
                     <key>138</key>
                     <value>406</value>
                  </associativeentity>
               </bundle_option>
               <bundle_option_qty i:null="true" />
               <links i:null="true" />
            </shoppingcartproductentity>
         </products>
         <storeId>1</storeId>
      </shoppingCartProductRemove>
   </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

The configurable product is 5730 ... this have associated a simple product (id: 5735) with the attributes:

attributeID = 92  value = color  (Attribute)

valueID =  410    value = black   (Attribute Options)

attributeId = 138  value = Size (Attribute)

valueId = 406      value = tall (Attribute Options)

What is wrong? . How do I can remove a configurable product?